# Checkbox fire a function if checked and a different function if not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have got a checkbox and when i click it and check the box a function runs, which works just how i want it to.. now i want to run a DIFFERENT function if it is checked off but it is just running the same function everytime.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="no-custom" onclick="CheckBox()">
```

```
function CheckBox() {
    $("#emailMain").css({"display": "none"});
    $("#emailSame").css({"display": "inline"});
    var Mainemail = Customer().email['#text']();
    Contact().email = Mainemail;
    EmailHolder(Mainemail);
}
```

Any ideas in the best way to sort this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you've included jQuery in your page you should use it to attach your events as its a better separation of concerns. You can then use the `checked` property of the element to determine which function to call:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="no-custom" />
```

```js
$('.no-custom').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        // do something...
    }
    else {
        // do something else...
    }
});
```

Comment: Love this answer.. just getting to grips with jquery and i want to use best practice and this works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="the-checkbox" class="no-custom" onclick="CheckBox()">
```

Then add an event listener for when it changes:

```
$(function() {

    $('#the-checkbox').change(function() {

        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            oneFunction();
        }
        else {
            anotherFunction();
        }

    });

    function oneFunction() {

    }

    function anotherFunction() {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if the checkbox is checked using [jQuery is](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
<input type="checkbox" class="no-custom" onclick="CheckBox(this)">

function CheckBox(cb) {
  if ($(cb).is(":checked")) {
    alert("Checked");
    CheckedFunction();
  } else {
    alert("Unchecked");
    UncheckedFunction
  }
}
```